# How to add radio button in a quiz app in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a quiz app and currently, I have just a button as my option but I want to choose radio buttons as my options and I also want to have a submit feature.

This is my code:

```
    <>
        {showScore ? null : <div>Countdown: {counter}</div>}
        <div className="question_no">
            <span>Question {currentQuestion + 2}</span>/{questions.length}
        </div>
        <div className="quiz-container">
            {showScore ? (
                <div className="score">
                    You scored {score} out of {questions.length}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <div className="quiz-header">
                        <div className="question">
                            {questions[currentQuestion].questionText}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="answer_div">
                        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map(
                            (answerOption) => (
                                <button
                                    onClick={() =>
                                        handleAnswerOptionClick(
                                            answerOption.isCorrect
                                        )
                                    }
                                >
                                    {answerOption.answerText}
                                </button>
                            )
                        )}
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    </>
```

how can i change the button option to radio button

Answer (score 0):

Radio is not a button type, but an input type, so probably something like this:

```
<div className="answer_div">
  {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map(
    (answerOption) => (
      <input type="radio" id={answerOption.answerID}
        onClick={() =>
          handleAnswerOptionClick(
            answerOption.isCorrect
          )
        }
      />
      <label htmlFor={answerOption.answerID}>
         {answerOption.answerText}
      </label>
    )
  )}
</div>
```

Maybe you wanna also use `onChange` instead of onClick.

Comment: The radio buttons are visible but  the answer options are not there.

Comment: Ops, the input syntax was wrong. You need a label to display something together with the radio, I edited the answer to have that. Keep in mind I'm using `answerOption.answerID` as the id for the input, you might need to declare this property or use another one.

Comment: Does this since your problem?